# download certain tables from mysql server to particular location as csv files

Tags: excel, vba

1. connect to mysql database.
2. should give user input which table to download from database.
3. selected table should get downloaded to particular location and save as a csv file. note csv name should be tablename.csv.

   ```
   Sub connect()
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    'OMIT Dim Cn statement
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    'OMIT Dim rs statement

    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 'EBGen-Daily
    Server_Name = "localhost"
    Database_Name = "testdb" ' Name of database
    User = "root" 'id user or username
    Password = "zxcasdQWE123" 'Password

    SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM vector"

    Set Cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 'NEW STATEMENT
    Cn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};Server=" & _
            Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
            ";User=" & User & ";Password=" & Password & "; Option=3;"

    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic

    Dim myArray()
    Dim ostream As Object

    myArray = rs.GetRows()

    kolumner = UBound(myArray, 1)
    rader = UBound(myArray, 2)

    Set ostream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    ostream.Open 
    'ostream.WriteText "hi, hello" & vbNewLine & "how, are" ' test input. not for any use
    ostream.SaveToFile ("C:\Users\asus\Downloads\vector.csv")
    ostream.Close

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing
   End Sub
   ```

I have connected to my database and selected a table for eg and put into array. now i am struck with how to download that table as csv's. and make user input on which table to select from database.
Can anyone help me with it.

Comment: Can anyone help me out

Comment: Create a temporary workbook , write the recordset to it with copyfromrecordset and then save as CSV.

Comment: can you tell me how to do it. and how to give table name as user input. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new workbook, copy records to sheet using CopyFromRecordset and then save as CSV.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateCSV()

    ' logon credentials
    Const Server_Name = "localhost"
    Const Database_Name = "testdb" ' Name of database
    Const User = "root" 'id user or username
    Const Password = "zxcasdQWE123" 'Password
     
    ' connect
    Dim Cn As Object, sCn As String, rs As Object
    Set Cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 'NEW STATEMENT
    Cn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver}" & _
            ";Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
            ";User=" & User & ";Password=" & Password & "; Option=3;"
    
    ' get list of tables
    Dim arTbl, n As Long, sTbl As String, msg As String, u As Variant
    Set rs = Cn.Execute("SHOW TABLES")
    arTbl = rs.getrows()
    
    For n = 1 To UBound(arTbl, 2)
        msg = msg & n & ") " & arTbl(0, n - 1) & vbLf
    Next
    u = InputBox(msg, "Select Table")
    
    ' check user input is valid
    If IsNumeric(u) Then
       If u < 1 Or u > UBound(arTbl, 2) Then
            MsgBox u & " is an invalid entry !", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
       End If
    Else
       MsgBox u & " is an invalid entry !", vbExclamation
       Exit Sub
    End If
    ' selected table
    sTbl = arTbl(0, u - 1)
    
    ' execute query
    Dim wbCSV As Workbook, wb As Workbook, filename As String
    Set rs = Cn.Execute("SELECT * FROM " & sTbl)
    
    ' create workbook, save as csv
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Add(1)
    filename = wb.Path & "\" & sTbl & ".csv"
    
    With wbCSV.Sheets(1)
        ' header
        For n = 1 To rs.Fields.Count
           .Cells(1, n) = rs.Fields(n - 1).Name
        Next
        ' data
        .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
        n = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .SaveAs filename, xlCSV
        wbCSV.Close savechanges:=False
    End With

    MsgBox n - 1 & " rows exported to " & filename, vbInformation
       
End Sub
```